# Probability that you always see more heads than tails

Tags: probability

The following question popped into my head: if you flip a biased coin infinitely many times with probability p > 1/2 of seeing a head, then what is the probability that after every step, the total number of heads seen is at least the number of tails seen? I've tried a proof by counting the number of such sequences (cf. the Catalan numbers) but I wasn't able to prove anything.

Comment: This link might help: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72025/probability-of-always-more-heads-than-tails

Comment: There is a distinction between "more heads than tails" and "at least as many".   $2p-1$ in the first case and $2-\dfrac{1}{p}$ in the second, and it is not a coincidence that the first is $p$ times the second